# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] ngAnimate AngularJS 1.2

Tags: angularjs

I'm getting **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]** by the time that I run my application, as far I know with this update to 1.2 there are several functionalities that are no longer part of the core, I've downloaded the angular-animage.js and the all the rest of external dependencies, for all the files  the version is the same **AngularJS v1.2.0-rc.2**

I also have added the dependency to my app.js as follows:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('mseApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.select2', 'facebook', 'ngCookies', 'ngAnimate', 'ngRoute']).config(//mode configurations here);
```

My js references:

```
  <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular.min.js")'> </script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js")'> </script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js")'></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js")'></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-0.6.0.min.js")'></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/select2.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-animate.min.js")'></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-facebook.js")'></script>
    <script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-cookies.min.js")'></script>
```

if I remove ngAnimate dependency it works just fine...

**EDIT**
[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/LXXHdq?p=preview) is the plunker.

If I add the ng-route to the references it broke the app.

Comment: plz put code on jsfiddle

Comment: I've updated with the plunker preview..thanks!

Comment: I have the same issue with ngAnimate, Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] when add ngAnimate and ngRoute... any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With regards to the Plnkr, the issue is the following:

in angularjs-1.2.0-rc.2-animate-app.js, you have defined your module as follows:

```
var myApp = angular.module('mseApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
```

While in your HTML, you have referred to the ng-app as follows:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
```

For AngularJS to pick up the module you have defined, you need the ng-app to refer to the module name you have specified in your JS. So it should in fact read:

```
<html ng-app="mseApp">
```

Making this change gets your app to work